# Why I only get the value of the last row in my table when I click the 'AddToCart' in other row

Tags: php, html

I have this code in php

```
<div style="width:75%;height: 600px;float: left;overflow-x: auto;">
        <form method="POST" action="addtocart.php">
            <table class="table" style="overflow-x: auto; width: 900px;">

            <tr>
                <th class="danger" id="th">Items</th>
                <th class="danger" id="th">Price(PhP)</th>
                <th class="danger" id="th">Quantity</th>
                <th class="danger" id="th">Action</th>
            </tr>

                <?php
                $item=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from store");
                while($pqrow=mysqli_fetch_array($item)){
                    $iid=$pqrow['id_item'];

                ?>
            <tr>
                <td class="warning" id="td">
                    <?php echo $pqrow['item']; ?></td>
                <td class="warning" id="td"><input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?php echo $pqrow['price']; ?>"><?php echo $pqrow['price']; ?></td>
                <td class="warning" id="td"><input type="number" style="width: 70px;" name="qty" value="1"></td>
                <td class="warning" id="td"><input type="hidden" name="item" value="<?php echo $iid; ?>"><input class="btn btn-success btn-md" type="submit" name="addtocart" value="AddToCart<?php echo $iid; ?>"></td>
            </tr><?php } ?>


        </table></form>
    </div>
```

When I click AddToCart in first row, the value of the last row has been fetch. I want to get the id and the input quantity when I click the AddToCart in 1st row.

Comment: In a simple way - because you have multiple fields with same name `item`. Value of the next field overwrites value of a previous one.

Comment: how can I make them different so that when I click the AddToCart in the first row I will get the id and the quantity of the first row. Thanks @u_mulder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have only one `form` tag and multiple `input`s with same name on this form, value of next input overwrites previous one. As a result you **always** have value of the last row.

You can fix it for example with creating a **separate** form for every row, e.g:

```
<div style="width:75%;height: 600px;float: left;overflow-x: auto;">
    <table class="table" style="overflow-x: auto; width: 900px;">
        <tr>
            <th class="danger" id="th">Items</th>
            <th class="danger" id="th">Price(PhP)</th>
            <th class="danger" id="th">Quantity</th>
            <th class="danger" id="th">Action</th>
        </tr>
    <?php
        $item = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from store");
        while ($pqrow=mysqli_fetch_array($item)) {
            $iid=$pqrow['id_item'];?>
        <tr>
            <td class="warning" id="td">
                <?php echo $pqrow['item']; ?></td>
            <td class="warning" id="td"><?php echo $pqrow['price']; ?></td>
            <td class="warning" id="td"><input type="number" style="width: 70px;" name="qty" value="1"></td>
            <td class="warning" id="td">
                <!-- Separate form for each record -->
                <form method="POST" action="addtocart.php">
                    <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?php echo $pqrow['price']; ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="item" value="<?php echo $iid; ?>">
                    <input class="btn btn-success btn-md" type="submit" name="addtocart" value="AddToCart<?php echo $iid; ?>">
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

In this case you should track with javascript the value of quantity field. Of course, you can move `<input type="number">` in a form too, but this will break your markup.

Also, if you're familiar with javascript, you can add some client preprocessing (getting values from `input`s of a certain row) and use ajax-request to send these values to server.

Comment: I'm familiar with js but not with ajax-request. Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: I already tried your code but I still get the same id in every row @u_mulder